# Dispatcher Servlet and AngularJs Router

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, jsp

I am trying to write a very simple application using Spring & AngularJs to understand the concept.
I am struggling to understand that how dispatcher servlet is behaving in this case.

**JSP Pages Location**

Project -> WebContent -> WEB-INF -> pages

hello.jsp

view1.jsp

view2.jsp

**Dispatcher Servlet**

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.job.controller" />

<mvc:resources mapping="include/**" location="/include/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="app/**" location="/app/" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**HelloController**

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/welcome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "First Try for Sprinv MVC, Angular JS and BootStrap");
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

**hello.jsp** - just AngularJs router code.

```
 var moduleConfig = function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/',
                        {
                            controller: 'SimpleController',
                            templateUrl: 'view1.jsp'
                        })
                .when('/second',
                        {
                            controller: 'FirstController',
                            templateUrl: 'view2.jsp'
                        })
                .otherwise(
                                { redirectTo: '/'}
                            );
};

myAppName.config(moduleConfig);
```

**Call**

```
http://localhost:8080/job/welcome
```

This brings the hello.jsp up and try to call templateUrl: 'view1.jsp'

and I get this error:

GET `http://localhost:8080/job/view1.jsp` 404 (Not Found)

I have tried all combinations but can not map request to appropriate jsps.

I am sure I am doing some fundamental mistake here. Please point out.

Comment: Right... the servlet doesn't respond to 'javascript' routing. You can't route jsp's via javascript.

Comment: Take a look at [jhipster](http://jhipster.github.io/) if your new to Spring and Angular... see how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your angularjs router will try to fetch template that points to your url.

With this configuration:

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    controller: 'SimpleController',
    templateUrl: 'view1.jsp'
  })
  .when('/second', {
    controller: 'FirstController',
    templateUrl: 'view2.jsp'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
```

AngularJS expect that your first template is located at `http://localhost:8008/job/view1.jsp` and your second template at `http://localhost:8008/job/view2.jsp` (I suppose that `http://localhost:8080/job` is the path to access your application).

With your spring mvc configuration, these url does not respond anything, that's why you see error 404 when AngularJS try to fetch your template. What you should do is probably to point to real templates (plain html file).

A second option could be to point to url managed by spring that will only be used to serve your templates.

I agree with comments, take a look at jhipster project to bootstrap a new project very quickly and to understand how it works.